# Xcode debugger can't show the value of [AnyObject] array when calling from Objective-C codes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, debugging

I use Swift classes in my old Objective-C project. When debugging the swift codes called from objective-c I find that Xcode debugger can't show the value of [AnyObject].

If I change the array type to a specific type, say [String], the debugger can then show the values. So I feel this may be a swift bug. But since I am new to swift I am not so sure. Can anyone cast some light on it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported this bug to apple, they let me try Xcode 7.3 beta 5 to see if that fixed the problem. Unfortunately it didn't. So I think I can say for sure that this is a bug.

Update: this bug has been fixed in Xcode 7.3